# showing text under a circle when hovering over the circle

Tags: javascript, html, css, knockout.js

I need to have text underneath the circle when I hover over it. I have to use html, css and javascript. I'm not that good with javascript so I know thats the problem. Any help would be appreciated and if there is a simpler way to do the javascript code that would be good too!

Here is my html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
</head>
    <body>

<p>I often scribble in the sand</p>
<p>The words I find so hard to say</p>
<p>And hope the wind will come along</p> 
<p>And blow them all your way.</p>
    <div data-bind="event: { mouseover: EnableDetails, mouseout: DisableDetails   
}"></div>
<p data-bind="visible: DetailsViewable(), text: AuthorName"></p>         
</body>
</html>
```

here is my css code

```
div {
display: inline-block;
margin-left: 5px;
height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    border:2px solid black;
    background-color: black;
    }
```

here is my javascript code:

```
var ViewModel = function() {
var self = this;
self.AuthorFirstName = ko.observable("Joe");
self.AuthorLastName = ko.observable("Blow");
self.AuthorName = ko.computed(function(){
    return self.AuthorFirstName() + " " + self.AuthorLastName();
});
self.DetailsViewable = ko.observable(false);
self.EnableDetails = function() {
    self.DetailsViewable(true);
};
self.DisableDetails = function() {
    self.DetailsViewable(false);
};
};

var viewModel = new ViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Comment: Your code looks fine to me. You will need to call your JS code onDomReady.  http://jsfiddle.net/CodingDawg/XPDTm/

Comment: I cant get it to work in dreamweaver or in a browser

Answer (score 4):

You can do this all with CSS.

http://jsfiddle.net/hzpKu/

```
div {
display: inline-block;
margin-left: 5px;
height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    border:2px solid black;
    background-color: black;
    }

div:hover + p {
    display:block;
}

p {
    display:none; 
}
```

Comment: Javascript has to be used. I need to change the javacript to simpler code and not use knockout framework. I need for the user to hover over the circle and other information popup. Also for some reason it wont open in any browser or dreamweaver.

Comment: It is not clear to me what your problem is. You asked to show text up under the circle when you hover using CSS/Javascript/HTML. The code above does this. Now it sounds like you have a bigger problem going on than just making something show up when you hover. You should make the code function before worrying about layout/hover events. Can't paint the picture without the canvas. You need to dig deeper and be more descriptive "It wont open for some reason" tells us nothing. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Why not try with Jquery?  is more easy with it.
http://jquery.com
(just download the plug in and put in the header)

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<style>
div {
display: inline-block;
margin-left: 5px;
height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    border:2px solid black;
    background-color: black;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>I often scribble in the sand</p>
<p>The words I find so hard to say</p>
<p>And hope the wind will come along</p> 
<p>And blow them all your way.</p>
    <div id="circle"></div>
<p id="circle_text"></p>

<script>
$( "#circle" ).hover(function() {
    $("#circle_text").text("Joe Blow");
  }, function() {
    $("#circle_text").text( "" );
  });
</script>         
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try something like this with a little bit of jquery...

 **[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FZAs4/1/)**

```
<div id="circle"></div>
<div id="text">
   ...
</div>

$('#circle').on('mouseenter', function () {
   $('#text').show("slow");
});
   $('#circle').on('mouseout', function () {
   $('#text').hide("slow");
});
```

**Updated:**

 or you can do it with less code by using `hover` and `toggle`

```
$('#circle').hover( function () {
  $('#text').toggle("slow");
});
```

[**Live Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/FZAs4/2/)

Comment: How would i keep the prose above the circle and add different information below the circle?

Comment: @user3727278 you mean something like this?: [Live Demo 3](http://jsfiddle.net/FZAs4/3/)